# App crashes in runtime in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, runtime

```
 return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Here's my stack trace:

```
2016-02-18 23:51:46.695 Lab3[9315:323419] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x7fdb6053b5d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key billAmountTextField.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f975e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f3eedeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f975aa9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010efbb9bb -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010feb1320 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001100dff41 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f8b64a0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001100de924 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010feb7eea -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010feb8816 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010feb8b74 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010feb92e7 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010fd8fab0 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 61
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010fd90199 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010fda1c2e -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010fd1a663 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4131
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010fd20cc6 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1760
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010fd1de7b -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001126ee754 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001126eeac2 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f8a1a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f89795c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f896e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f896828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010fd1d7cd -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010fd22610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    26  Lab3                                0x000000010eeec1bf main + 111
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001120b192d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: hey man, formatting this into more of a question and not a general I have an error here is my log question will get you a lot further. Try to pinpoint a general area you're having a problem. Show that code. And tell us what is happening and what you intend to happen.

Comment: I agree, please show us your code involving 'billAmountTextField'